# Where to store image if the image is used in two different websites

Tags: angularjs, image-processing, asp.net-web-api, image-uploading

I want to upload the image in my website. The same image will be shown in another website. So this is the scenario where image is uploaded in one website and displayed in both website. These two websites are hosted in two different servers as well as they both have their own database.

I am using Angular JS, Entity Framework, Web API  and SQL Server 2014 as backend for both of the website. Currently I am using ngFileUpload to upload the images. Please answer me on below questions:-

1. Should I upload the image in database(as nvarchar-max) or filesystem(FTP or local web server file system)? I read many articles and get to know that Database retrieval of image has affect on performance but it is more secured. However File System is easy in performance but complex on maintenance like back ups. So I am just not able to decide which to choose among these two as both have pros and cons. Which option will be more suitable to my requirement where same image will be displayed in both website. Please note that there can big images like upto 5 MB uploaded in the application but the number of images will not be huge as compare to any social networking or online shopping site.
2. How to create different size of images(thumbnail, medium, large etc) automatically upon uploading of image in website? Is there any tool or directive already available in Angular JS to achieve this?

I know my question is broad but I need suggestion to start with my requirements.
Please help.

Comment: There are a few options for you to store the images. One is AWS S3. It provides environment good for st is storing data. The second one I can suggest is google firebase. You could firebase services to store and fetch data to the databases. About the second query I'm not sure of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use the file system to host my images.  If the image is displayed on someone's computer screen, they can use an image capturing software to copy it anyway.  Also, while storing them to a database may be more secure, I don't need the extra overhead in my code where a simple url to retrieve the image will suffice.

As for resizing an image using Angular, check out these links:
https://www.scientiamobile.com/page/angular-image-resize
https://github.com/FBerthelot/angular-images-resizer